# How to layout a page having one fixed dimetion element and one liquid element?

Tags: css, layout

How to do the following layout without using tables:

left element(100px)|right element (occupies what ever space is remaining, even when there is no content)

Thanks

Edit: link to code: http://pastebin.com/vU33jNxD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Float the left element and give the right element a left margin of 100px.

Comment: @Luke: As I wanted both the elements to occupy the page regardless of whether they hold any content, I'm using absolute positioning and specifying the width of right element as 100%. So when I floated left element (to left) and gave the right element 100px left margin, I get a horizontal scroll bar :(. Any way to avoid this ? Here is a link of the code so far: http://pastebin.com/vU33jNxD

Comment: Depending on how you want this to flow once you add real content, the following hack might work. It's far from good code, though. http://pastebin.com/JMCJbxah

Comment: Very interesting :) . Works in FF, Chrome. breaks in IE.

Comment: Somehow, that fails to surprise me. If you want a more robust solution, I'd look at handling it in javascript. It's also bugging me that alquantoun's answer isn't working in my tests. I'm pretty sure he has it right, but maybe there's some quirk with having no content.

Comment: Ya, I guess handling in javascript is one option. AFAIK, display:block is effective only when width/height is mentioned which is why the div collapses.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the 100% width for the `#right` div. This will make it so there isn't an extra 100px to the right of the screen.

Comment: This makes the right div collapse down to the width of the content

Comment: divs are usually displayed as blocks by default, but you can add `display:block` to the `#right` div to ensure the width isn't determined by the content.

Comment: I feel like this is correct, but that's not how it's behaving in my quick (probably flawed) tests.

Comment: ahh, it's the absolute position. I think this is unnecessary as well on both elements. With the float given, the position for both elements doesn't need to be given... I forgot that I took them out.

Comment: Would you mind pastebin-ing your code? It's still acting strange for me and now I'm all curious.

Comment: Huh. That is correct, it just wasn't working in jsfiddle. Should have tested somewhere else. Thanks.

Comment: no prob. You had me scratching my head for a while trying to figure that out! Glad it works though!

Comment: Works perfectly in FF,chrome,IE. Thanks alquatoun!